# Probability measures on a Polish space

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space, that is a separable metric complete topological space. Is the space of Borel probability measures on $X$, equipped with its weak topology, is Polish too ?

It is metric, but what about completeness and separability ?

Comment: If probability measures means Borel probability measures then yes. This is proved e.g. in Kechris, Classical descriptive set theory, [Theorem 17.23, page 112](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC&pg=PA112).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is (under the topology of weak convergence). This follows from Theorem 6.2 and Theorem  6.5 in [Probability Measures on Metric Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082183889X) by K. R. Parthasarathy, which is a good reference for these kind of questions.

Comment: there does not seem to be a thm 6.5 in the book you mention

Comment: There is on page 46.