# How the weak$^*$ topology of the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$ is defined?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, complete-spaces, borel-measures

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then @Nate Eldredge [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574383/measurability-of-the-pushforward-operator-on-measures?rq=1#comment5397566_574627) that

> The space $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of probability measures on a Polish space $X$, endowed with the **weak topology** (induced by bounded continuous functions), is first countable - **indeed Polish**. This is a standard result that you can find in, say, Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*. Note here that the **"weak topology" is really a weak$^*$ topology.** You can think about the fact that, given a separable Banach space $W$, the weak* topology on $W^*$ is not first countable, but the topology it induces on the ball of $W^*$ is first countable (indeed, Polish!).

1. In Onno van Gaans's note [Probability measures on metric spaces](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/jancol1.pdf), I got that

- **Theorem 4.2** If $X$ is separable, then the weak topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is separable.
- **Proposition 5.3** If $X$ is compact, then the weak topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is compact.

Could you elaborate on which theorem in Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures* mentiones that if $X$ is Polish then the weak topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is Polish?

2. From Riesz–Markov–Kakutani theorem, it seems to me weak$^*$ topology is induced by the space $C_0 (X)$ of continuous functions on $X$ vanishing at infinity, but I'm not sure. Could you elaborate on how the  weak$^*$ topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is defined?

Comment: Your broad question ("is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ polish when $X$ is?") has been asked before, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97408/655547), for instance. I'm not voting to close because it seems like you might want a reference in Billingsley in particular? Or maybe you want more information on what the weak topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is? Either way, you can find this as theorem 17.23 in Kechris's _Classical Descriptive Set Theory_. This is in chapter 17.E, which is all about the space of (borel) probability measures on a polish space $X$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you for answering my first question! Do you have any hint for the second one?

Comment: The weak-* topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is, as I said, the one induced by the bounded continuous functions.  Specifically, the weakest topology such that for every bounded continuous function $f$, the map $\mu \mapsto \int f\,d\mu$ is continuous.  If $X$ is locally compact, then this is the same as the topology induced by $C_0(X)$, but in general it is not.

Comment: @NateEldredge The term "weak$^*$ topology" usually arises from the weak$^*$ topology of the dual space of a TVS. If we use the term "weak$^*$ topology" for the one induced by $C_0(X)$, then it makes sense by Riesz–Markov–Kakutani theorem. However, I could not understand how we use the term "weak$^*$ topology" for the one induced by $C_b(X)$. Could you elaborate more?